# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String i am getting this error

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int WeekId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["WeekId"]);
            if (((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek) != WeekId)
            {
                Response.Write("<h4>Sorry! Today is NOT the week you selected. Please use Back button of browser and try again!</h4>");
                Response.End();
            }
            lblToday.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            lblWeekId.Text = Request.QueryString["WeekId"];
            lblPeriod.Text = Request.QueryString["period"];
            lblSemister.Text = Request.QueryString["Semester"];
        }
```

Comment: Where's the error? I am assuming it is in the first line `int WeekId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["WeekId"]);`

Comment: Which value is null? Try changing `int WeekId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["WeekId"]);` to `int WeekId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["WeekId"] ?? string.Empty);` to protect against null.

Comment: This error is not in this code.

Comment: its giving me this error "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String" against this line "int WeekId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["WeekId"]);"

Comment: The parameter `WeekId` could be empty in your url

Answer (score 0):

Just add your link with this one (or likes)

```
xxxThisIsYourLinkxxx?WeekId=yyy
```

`yyy` can be change to integer value (e.g. 1,2 or likes)

Answer (score 0):

Your `querystring` value is `null`. Make sure that `querystring` is being `passed` to this page. Also for a better approach put your code in `try catch` block.

```
try{
      int WeekId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["WeekId"]);
      if (((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek) != WeekId)
       {
                Response.Write("<h4>Sorry! Today is NOT the week you selected. Please use Back button of browser and try again!</h4>");
                Response.End();
       }
        lblToday.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        lblWeekId.Text = Request.QueryString["WeekId"];
        lblPeriod.Text = Request.QueryString["period"];
        lblSemister.Text = Request.QueryString["Semester"];
   }
catch(Exception ex)
{
 //Handle exception here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this question quickly with the limited information you have provided.

First off you didn't provide the line that the error was applicable to however it appears obviously in the first statement where you are trying to convert a value form the querystring without checking if the value infact exists and is not null (hence the error). Now there can be many different ways to go about this but can be solved really quickly.

`int WeekId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["WeekId"]);` <-- Assuming this is the error line.

Basic Resolution:

```
int weekId = 0;

//first try and parse the int from the query string. Note the  ?? will execute the statement 
//following when the result is null. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx
if (!int.TryParse((Request.QueryString["WeekId"] ?? ""), out weekId))
{
    Response.Write("<h4>Sorry! You didnt select a valid week. Please use Back button of browser and try again!</h4>");
    Response.End();
}

//next lets check the value of the day of week.. 
if (((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek) != weekId)
{
    Response.Write("<h4>Sorry! Today is NOT the week you selected. Please use Back button of browser and try again!</h4>");
    Response.End();
}
```

Simplified Solution:

```
int weekId = -1;
//first try and parse the int from the query string. Note the  ?? will execute the statement 
//following when the result is null. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx
//the test the day of week parsed
if (!int.TryParse((Request.QueryString["WeekId"] ?? ""), out weekId) || ((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek) != weekId)
{
    Response.Write("<h4>Sorry! Today is NOT the week you selected. Please use Back button of browser and try again!</h4>");
    Response.End();
}
```